# Toolboxes are huge in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to resize docked toolboxes in inkscape? I dock toolboxes towards the right of my screen (see image below) but it is taking up too much space compared to my drawing layer. Dragging it by the three dots I can only completely hide it, not resize it. I use inkscape version 1.1.1

[image]

Comment: Try with the new version (inkscape 1.2)

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version of Inkscape. This was an issue when you had certain larger dialogs open - especially the document set up. The only real way to deal with it was to close the offending dialog.  I suggest you update to the most recent Inkscape 1.2. They appear to have fixed this issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Close page setup tab, it makes all other tabs wider.

In 1.2 it was fixed, and you can resize tab to its minimum width, though.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal width of the toolbox is dependent *on its current displayed content (dialog)*, e.g., the `Transform` dialog may be narrower than the `Document properties` one.

You may always *hide the dock* by clicking at the center of its left side:
[image]

(To unhide it, click at the center of the narrow bar which remained after hiding it).

Comment: It is not the case for 1.1